# Is battery self-discharge cumulative with discharge from use?

Tags: batteries, discharge

Imagine a battery with a self-discharge rate of `X`. If I hook it up to a circuit that draws `Y`, is the battery draining at `X + Y`, `MAX(X, Y)`, or some other function?

Does the answer depend on battery chemistry?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is additive (X+Y) but as I'm not completely certain I'll let others answer. But I wanted to comment that this is a fantastically well-written question.

Comment: @JYelton thanks. I spent quite some time trimming off all of the irrelevant bits of word vomit that made up my question in its original formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly summarizing the paper *Generalized Model for Self-Discharge Processes
in Alkaline Batteries* by Galushkin et al. (2012)<sup>1</sup>, the self-discharge process can be modeled by a non-linear resistor and capacitor in parallel, in which the alkaline battery discharges until reaching a *critical voltage* which is dependent on its chemistry.

My interpretation of this paper is that the self-discharge process runs parallel to the circuit, such that the battery is draining both due to self-discharge and through its primary function of providing energy to the device.

In other words, the answer (for alkaline batteries, at least) appears to be X + Y, with the caveat that X is a function of time and, if the battery is discharged enough, may be zero.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Link to abstract here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/2.081208jes/meta) but unfortunately you'll need institutional access to get the full paper.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to wait to see if other answers crop up, in case other battery chemistries do change the answer.

Comment: I've found a couple models of lithium batteries, but mostly to model internal impedance. None that specifically address self-discharge. Certainly nothing that implies a part of the circuit "turns off" when a load is applied. Nonetheless, I suspect if your load is small enough that self-discharge is a meaningful percentage of battery drain, then self-discharge will happen whether or not your load is currently connected. An interesting case would be one where self-discharge *decreases* with increased temperature, but I suspect a particularly exotic material would be necessary for that to occur.

Comment: (And since I'm not a physicist, I can't even begin to speculate if such a thing is even possible.)

Comment: Context here is my Tesla Powerwall, where the self-discharge is about 4% per day. I'm analyzing whether it is more optimal to use the battery to run my house off grid as much as possible vs using it in emergency backup only. This was useful to know that using the battery isn't going to prevent self-discharge, but self-discharge should decrease as the battery discharges, so I would probably lose less energy to self-discharge by using the battery than I am by trying to keep it topped off all the time.

Comment: A few percent per day?! The cells themselves should be losing at worst a few percent *per month*. What else is running in there?

Comment: I don't know; there could be more than just self-discharge, but whatever it is doesn't show up as a draw from the battery. 28kWh of batteries requires a 1-2kWh recharge every day to keep them topped up.